# set state is not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the state hook in my react app.

But `setTodos` below seems not updating the `todos` 
link to my work: https://kutt.it/oE2jPJ
link to github: https://github.com/who-know-cg/Todo-react

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Main from "./component/Main";

const Application = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  // add todo to state(todos)
  const addTodos = message => {
    const newTodos = todos.concat(message);
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Main
        addTodos={message => addTodos(message)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

And in my main.js

```
const Main = props => {
  const input = createRef();
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={input} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.addTodo(input.current.value);
          input.current.value = "";
        }}
      >
        Add message to state
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I expect that every time I press the button, The `setTodos()` and `getTodos()` will be executed, and the message will be added to the `todos` array.

But it turns out the state is not changed. (still, stay in the default blank array)

Comment: Are you sure `getTodo()` is resolved? Does `successAlert()` work?

Comment: as you are not displaying the todos inside the render of your component, how can you determine that your state was not updated ?

Comment: I try to console.log(todos), is it able to show the todos ?

Comment: i tried your github code and it seems it is adding items to todos. so how can you say message is not being added to todos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update state of the parent component, you should pass down the function from the parent to child component.

Here is very simple example, how to update state with hook from child (Main) component.

With the help of a button from child component you update state of the parent (Application) component.

```
const Application = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = message => {
    let todosUpdated = [...todos, message];
    setTodos(todosUpdated);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Main addTodo={addTodo} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(todos, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

const Main = props => {
  const input = createRef();
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={input} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.addTodo(input.current.value);
          input.current.value = "";
        }}
      >
        Add message to state
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Demo is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-cache-9y7dl

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use this in my code. but it turn out like this (it will console.log(todos) after addTodos ) https://kutt.it/oE2jPJ  ( º﹃º ) what is happening to my app

Comment: Try your own code, mine was just as an example for you to better understand how setState hook work, just make sure you use `<Main addTodos={addTodos} />`.

Comment: If you have your code in git repository, you could add link in your question, so we can get better picture of what's happening in your app.

Comment: thank you for your advise, I added it to the question. https://github.com/who-know-cg/Todo-react

Comment: Well, the problem is not with adding item :) I will fork your app and fix it.

Comment: The problem was with removing items. 1. You run rmTodos on every render. Fix was to use arrow function. 2. Use filter to remove items form state instead of slice. Here is fixed version of your code - https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-react-m5g0h If this solution works for you, then select my answer as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass message as a parameter in Main, just the name of the function.

```
<Main addTodos={addTodos} />
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this method, but it still not work TAT. It turn out like this (try add todo with + button two times) https://kutt.it/4UUcGX

Comment: `this` keyword will not work as he declared a functional component, you could directly write `addTodos={addTodos}`

Answer (score 0):

In Application.jsx :

You can pass just a reference to addTodos here. The name on the left can be whatever you want.

```
  <Main addTodos={addTodos} />
```

In Main.jsx :

Since getTodo returns a Promise, whatever that promise resolves to will be your expected message.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing addTodos as prop.

```
<Main
    addTodos={message => addTodos(message)}
/>
```

However, in child component, you are accessing using

```
props.addTodo(input.current.value);
```

It should be `addTodos`.

```
props.addTodos(input.current.value);
```